# Coloring the outside of a circle using arcAngle

Tags: java, geometry

Question about the circumference of circles. In order to change the outside color of the circle (circumference) I would use

```
drawArc(int x, int y, int width, int height, int startAngle, int arcAngle)
```

Just not exactly how to start off after the following code below..after `Public void drawArc` I dont know where to go

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Dimension d = getSize();

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {                        
        Color color = new Color(generator.nextInt(255), generator.nextInt(255), generator.nextInt(255));
        g.setColor(color);

        int circleSize = generator.nextInt(d.width / 4);
        int x = generator.nextInt(d.width - circleSize);
        int y = generator.nextInt(d.height - circleSize);
        g.fillOval(x, y, circleSize, circleSize);
        g.drawArc(x, y, circleSize, circleSize, 0, 360);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you misunderstood your assignment?  I think your teacher wants you to use the `drawArc` method of the `Graphics` class, not write your own one.

Comment: @DavidWallace I agree and this is what I have changed it to but now I am stuck yet again..

Comment: @DavidWallace adding the statement to change the color did work thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are drawing the body of a circle, then drawing its outline, without changing the colour in between.  That means you can't actually see the outline of the circle.

I think you should change the colour of the graphics context, before you draw the outline.  One way would be to insert

```
color = new Color(generator.nextInt(255), generator.nextInt(255), generator.nextInt(255));
g.setColor(color);
```

before the call to `drawArc`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need your own drawArc method, you should be calling the [Graphics.drawArc()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawArc%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method. `x` and `y` are the center of the circle, `width` and `height` are the diameter of the circle, and `startAngle` and `arcAngle` are where to start and stop drawing the circle. 0 is 3 o'clock. So to draw a complete circle you would use 0 and 360 for `startAngle` and `arcAngle`.